# How to set pre-requisites requirement into a installer in C#?

Tags: c#

i am beginner for C#, anyone know how to set pre-requisites requirement into a installer in C#?

Comment: What kind of installer are you using ?

Comment: exe installer. I want to install .net framework 3.5sp1, crystal report 2008 and ms sql server 2005 before install my system

Answer (score 0):

With both a MSI installer and a clickonce installer, it's recommend to deploy a bootstrapper which ensures that .NET and optionally MSI are installed before launching your specific installer.

Please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5(v=vs.80).aspx for information on using a bootstrapper and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(v=vs.80).aspx for information on including pre-requisites into your MSI project